# jQuery on click and click again

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make it so that when a button is clicked then a class is given to it and when its clicked again the class is removed.

Could someone help?

```
    $("body").on("click", ".AudioShowHidePlaylist", function(event){
        $('.AudioShowHidePlaylist').addClass('active');
    });
```

Comment: @FelixKling, How do you find them so quickly? +1

Comment: @gdoron: I just... search :) [`[jquery] click class toggle`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[jquery]+click+class+toggle) ... of course I still have to skim the list and check the question(s), but IMO this takes about as long as writing a proper answer (in most cases).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply with [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/):

```
$("body").on("click", ".AudioShowHidePlaylist", function(event){
    $('.AudioShowHidePlaylist').toggleClass('active');
    // Or as @Felix commented below:
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Docs:

> Description: Add or remove one or more classes from each element in the set of matched elements, depending on either the class's presence or the value of the switch argument.

Comment: OP probably wants `$(this)` instead of `$('.AudioShowHidePlaylist')`, but who knows.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#foo').toggleClass(className, addOrRemove);
```

is equivalent to:

```
if (addOrRemove) {
   $('#foo').addClass(className);
 }
 else {
   $('#foo').removeClass(className);
}
```

UPDATE: [Read full article at http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

[Please click here to read more about toggle function](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_toggle.asp)

Comment: w3schools has a bad reputation of being incorrect or imprecise. There is no reason not to link to the official documentation: http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/.

Comment: well this vary person to person. i think w3schools has good learning material.

Comment: Only to some degree. If something is wrong, it's wrong, no matter who reads it. I'm not saying you should avoid w3schools at all costs, you should just be aware of it. To support my claim: http://w3fools.com/.

Comment: And what is `addOrRemove`? your answer isn't quite full. BTW, `addOrRemove== true`  does it mean it needs to be added or removed?

Comment: i am agreed with you. thanks for your feedback.